# Why is this code inconsistently crashing?

Tags: c++, debugging, pthreads

I'm writing a prime sieve program using eratosthenes' for class.  I have 8 threads going, each one responsible for a segment of the number range [1, 2^32].  For some reason, sometimes thread[0] in my threads array doesn't make it to the function that the thread goes to when it's created.  The other ones always (it seems) do.  Please let me know what's wrong with this code.  A warning though, I'm just learning C++, so there might be syntax errors, etc., which I assume is causing the bug.  Been spending hours on this and narrowed it down to the thread[0] not always making it to the function.  I changed the values of the #define's so it would be easier to debug.  Bug happens either way.  Please, I'm not too interested in other comments on how I could improve the program.  It's due soon, so I just want to get it working as it is.  Thanks so much!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <bitset>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_OF_THREADS 8
#define TWO_TO_THIRTY_SECOND 1000000 //4294967296
#define SQRT_TWO_TO_THE_THIRTY_SECOND 1000 //65536
#define TWO_T0_THIRTY_SECOND_OVER_EIGHT 125000 //536870976

typedef struct {
    unsigned long composite_to_remove_index;
    int thread_index;
    unsigned long prime_number;
} thread_info_t;

bitset<TWO_T0_THIRTY_SECOND_OVER_EIGHT> bitmap[NUM_OF_THREADS];
static pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_t thread[NUM_OF_THREADS];


static void * threadFunc(void *arg)
{

    thread_info_t info = *(thread_info_t *)arg;

    bitmap[info.thread_index][info.composite_to_remove_index] = 1;
    info.composite_to_remove_index += info.prime_number;

    int index_to_remove = (int)info.composite_to_remove_index;

    for(; index_to_remove < TWO_T0_THIRTY_SECOND_OVER_EIGHT; index_to_remove += info.prime_number)
    {
        if(bitmap[info.thread_index][index_to_remove] == 0)
        {
            bitmap[info.thread_index][index_to_remove] = 1;
            if(info.thread_index == 0)
            {
                cout << "bit " << index_to_remove << ": " << bitmap[info.thread_index][index_to_remove] << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{   
    int thread_ret_val;
    vector<unsigned long long> prime_numbers;
    thread_info_t info; 

    for(unsigned long long i = 2; i < SQRT_TWO_TO_THE_THIRTY_SECOND; i++)
    {
        if(bitmap[0][i] == 0)
        {
            prime_numbers.push_back(i);
            info.prime_number = i;

            for(unsigned long j = 0; j < NUM_OF_THREADS; j++)
            {
                if(j == 0)
                    info.composite_to_remove_index = i*2;
                else
                    info.composite_to_remove_index = (((TWO_TO_THIRTY_SECOND/NUM_OF_THREADS)*j) % i);
                info.thread_index = (int)j;


                thread_ret_val = pthread_create(&thread[info.thread_index], NULL, threadFunc, (void*)&info);
                if(thread_ret_val != 0)
                {
                    cerr << "create thread error " << strerror(thread_ret_val) << "\n";
                }
            }

            for(int j = 0; j < NUM_OF_THREADS; j++)
            {
                pthread_join(thread[j], NULL);
            }
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Inconsistently crashing. It's what threads _do_.

Comment: What is the stack when it crashes?  Without looking my guess is you're accessing bitmap on more than one thread without synchronization.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "doesn't make it to the function".  Does this program exhibit the same behavior when `NUM_OF_THREADS=1`?  If so, describe what you see when you step through the program in the debugger.  Also, is this homework?

Comment: well that's the problem, it doesn't even get to the function.  i put a breakpoint there and watch for it's thread_index to be 0.  is it ok for different threads to access different bitsets in the same array without synch?

Comment: and yes, the program is an assignment for class.  the prof said it was ok to get help from outside sources if we hit bugs :)

Comment: @jeffamaphone sorry, it doesn't crash, the thread just doesn't go to the function.  I have a if(info.thread_index == 0), and sometimes it gets caught, sometimes it doesn't.  when i set `NUM_OF_THREADS = 1`, it makes it to the function every time, but at `NUM_OF_THREADS = 2`, it does sometimes and doesn't sometimes.

Comment: It doesn't even compile (with a C compiler) let alone crash! -- C tag removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`info` structure that is passed to all threads is meant to be unique for each thread but is here inadvertently and occasionally shared between threads. The problem is that `info` is not guaranteed to be unchanged between the call to `pthread_create` and the beginning of `threadFunc`. After calling `pthread_create` you change the contents of `info` in next iteration, and it may happen that only then the previous thread actually copies `info` in the first line of `threadFunc`.

You should have `std::vector` of info structures, and call `pthread_create` every time with different `info`.

Comment: aha.  that makes sense.  if i didn't want to make a vector, couldn't i just declare the info struct in the for loop so it goes out of scope after every loop?

Comment: Structure must be alive when the the first line is executed, and this is not guaranteed with the loop. Either give each thread its own structure, or synchronize access to one shared structure. Latter is complicated and unnecessary here. Each thread really needs its own structure. On the plus side you don't have to copy the structure in the thread. Alternative to `std::vector` would be to create each info with `new`, pass it as pointer to `threadFunc`, use it there as pointer, and `delete` it at the end of the function.

Comment: I was thinking about just putting the pthread_t thread in the struct as well, then I could just have one array of structs.  think that's a bad idea?

Comment: You can do it, there's no problem with that.